# How to tell Mathematica do parallel computation?

Tags: parallelization, kernel, simulation, kernel-startup

I am using `NDSolve` on a workstation with 6 kernels. To speed up the simulation I have used `LaunchKernels[]` to load all the available parallel kernels. I am not sure whether or not this simple command makes the simulation a parallel computation? However, I found that the running time with `LaunchKernels[]` is the nearly the same order of that without `LaunchKernels[]`.

**My questions are:**

1. What on earth does `LaunchKernels[]` do for a particular computation? Or under what circumstances should I use `LaunchKernels[]`?
2. How do you tell Mathematica to compute parallelly on a workstation or a dual-core laptop? For example, how to parallelize this example:

   `fsol = NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x], 
   u[x, 0] == 1 - Sin[4*Pi*x]/(4*Pi), u[0, t] == 1, 
   u[1, t] + Derivative[1, 0][u][1, t] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 100}}];
   Plot[First[u[1, t] + Derivative[1, 0][u][1, t] /. fsol], {t, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: no that is not enough: you have to explicitly tell Mathematica to (attempt to) run an evaluation in parallel, through one of the [many commands](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ParallelComputing.html) available for this purpose, like `Parallelize`, `ParallelTable` and so on

Comment: I don't believe `NDSolve[]` is parallelizable.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the method `FiniteElement` instead of `TensorProductGrid` the parallelization is done automatically :

```
fsol = NDSolveValue[{
   D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x] + NeumannValue[-u[x, t], x == 1],
   u[x, 0] == 1 - Sin[4 Pi x]/(4 Pi),
   u[0, t] == 1
   },
  u,
  {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 3},
  MaxStepSize -> 0.0001,
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 0.001}}}}
  ]  

Manipulate[
 Plot[fsol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1.1}}], {t, 0, 
  1}]
```

[image]

On Windows, The parallelization is visible on the "Windows Task Manager"

`MaxStepSize-> 0.0001` and `"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 0.001}}` are used here to increase the computing time.